# unterminated regexp & unexpected newline

Tags: bash, shell-script, rhel

i got a error when `awk` command executed

```
echo $(awk 'BEGIN {printf "%.2f\n",'$sizes'/1073741824}')GB >> $MAINS/logs/bks1
```

that is for changing integers into a size (GB).
But i got error like this

```
awk: cmd. line:1: BEGIN {printf "%.2f GB\n",/1073741824}
awk: cmd. line:1:                            ^ unterminated regexp
awk: cmd. line:1: BEGIN {printf "%.2f GB\n",/1073741824}
awk: cmd. line:1:                                       ^ unexpected newline or end of string
```

Sometimes it works fine

Should i add sleep before that command executed ?
Thank you all, i appreciate your time and help.

Comment: i have updated my post

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When the `sizes` variable is empty it will be replaced with the empty string, as expected. And in the relevant portion of the script `awk` expects any string starting with a slash to be the start of a regular expression, but it's only a valid regular expression once it's terminated by another slash. You need to make sure `sizes` is not empty for the script to work.

`set -o nounset` to be notified of undefined (not empty) variables in your scripts, and combine with `-o errexit` to stop the script on such errors.

Comment: Thank you very much, Mr. l0b0
I think i need check if the sizes is null or not to prevent that error

Comment: @l0b0 I just thought you may want to say something about that in your answer, but since it may not be of interest, I'll remove that comment.